# Why don't all metals have closed pack structures?

Tags: material-science, crystals, metals

A lot of times, in my materials classes, metal atoms' behavior during deformation is described like a bunch of stacked balls. In my introduction to material class, our professors explained that metals want to form the most packed structure possible. But then why do other structures, like BCC exist? why don't they all form FCC structures?

Comment: See also: [Why \[do\] alkali metals have \[the\] bcc structure?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57484/why-alkali-metals-have-bcc-structure)

Comment: @my2cts - fcc and hcp are equally dense. The difference is stacking ABCABCABC vs ABABAB.

Comment: Correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only consider an isotropic interaction such as the classic 6-12 potential
$$
V(r) = V_0 (\frac{1}{(r/a)^{12}} - \frac{2}{(r/a)^6})
$$
then indeed you would always get the same crystal structure (in 2d this corresponds to a triangular lattice). But in materials we generally have more complicated potentials that include directional inter-atomic interactions. If you take the potential $V(r) = V_0 (\frac{1}{(r/a)^{12}} - \frac{1+\cos{4\theta}}{(r/a)^6})$ then you can check that you won't have a triangular lattice but instead a square lattice.

Comment: I have never been taught this in class. Could you tell me the name of the formula you listed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential

Answer (score 1):

...and the reason you get more complicated potentials is that p, d, and f orbitals are not spherically symmetric but have lobes sticking out at specific angles.